# How do you create a dynamic list source for Data Validation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, validation

Currently, I am using the below to retrieve a value for Data Validation, the problem is when I set it the `Source`, I get `The list source must be a delimited list, or a reference to a single row or column.` How do I go about making this usable as a Data Validation Source?

`=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A3,$A:$A,0)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A3,$A:$A,0)),",","|",1))+1,
LEN(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A3,$A:$A,0)))),",",REPT(" ",LEN(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A3,$A:$A,0))))),LEN(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A3,$A:$A,0)))))`

What I want to do, is do a Index/Match and find values from a column then retrieve the nth value.

For example:

1. Look up `MyValueA` in Column A
2. Return value in Column C (`MyValueC1, MyValueC2, MyValueC3`).
3. Data Validation is used as dropdown to allows user to select the 1st item or don't select anything.
4. Column M - User can use dropdown to select 1st item from Step 2 - In this case, `MyValueC1`
5. Similar for Columns N to R.

Things I can't use:

- UDF don't work in Data Validation
- Defined Names don't work because it sets the values to be static.

[image]

The cells coloured green are the cells that are supposed to have the data validation dropdown list for users to select Scenes.

- Row 1 is used as a header
- Row 2 is the summary descriptor for Scenario #1 which has three Scenes (Scene #1, Scene #2, Scene #3).
- Row 3 and 4 are used by the user to select the scenes they want to have a specific colour, but the Selection Columns (Columns M to R) using a Data Validation dropdown list are determined by the Scenes available to the Scenario.

  - Selection #1 is linked to Scene #1 of Scenario #1 for Row 3 and 4 (dropdown would show only Scene #1)
  - Selection #2 is linked to Scene #2 of Scenario #1 for Row 3 and 4 (dropdown would show only Scene #2)
  - Selection #3 is linked to Scene #3 of Scenario #1 for Row 3 and 4 (dropdown would show only Scene #3)
  - Selection #4 is linked to Scene #4 of Scenario #1 for Row 3 and 4 (but no Scene #4, so dropdown should show blank)
  - Selection #5 is linked to Scene #5 of Scenario #1 for Row 3 and 4 (but no Scene #5, so dropdown should show blank)
  - Selection #6 is linked to Scene #6 of Scenario #1 for Row 3 and 4 (but no Scene #6, so dropdown should show blank)

Then the same idea for Scenario #2 (Rows 5 and 6) and Scenario #3 (Rows 7 and 8)

Formulas that work in-cell, but not in Data Validation Source:

Selecting the first Scene from the list of Scenes from a cell in Column B:
`=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A3,A:A,0)), ",", "|", 1),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A3,A:A,0)), ",", "|", 1),1)-1)`

Selecting the second Scene from the list of Scenes from a cell in Column B:
`=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A3,$A:$A,0)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A3,$A:$A,0)),",","|",1))+1,
LEN(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A3,$A:$A,0)))),",",REPT(" ",LEN(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A3,$A:$A,0))))),LEN(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A3,$A:$A,0)))))`

Comment: what is the output of your formula (it's actually hard to test it)?

Comment: @simoco The output gives me exactly what I want if it was in a cell, I'll edit to explain it.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: @tigeravatar That link uses defined names, which don't work in a table of values, only if you're using one single validation value.

Comment: @Bob I'm afraid I don't understand your reply.  Do you mean you have more than one level of dependent data validation? You would probably be best off including some sample data with expected results/functionality.  Screenshots or a sample workbook would go a long way towards allowing us to help you effectively

Comment: @tigeravatar I've added a screenshot and tried to explain how the rows interact with each other and what I want for the data validation

Comment: @Bob. I think you need to restructure your sheet separating static data (i.e Scenes an scenario can have) & user selections. Are you ok with this?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you have:

1. A list of scenarios, 1 to 3 at least, and a list of scenes for each scenario.
2. A list of Scene Colours to apply to each scene *(4 choices as per the sample provided)*.
3. Selections, from 1 to 6, corresponding to each Scenario\Scene *(i.e. Selection #n always corresponds to Scenario #X \ Scene #n)*  therefore there is only one possible selection for each Scenario\Scene\Scene Colour.
4. A table to assign Scene Colours to each Scenario\Scene *(one Scenario\Scene might have several Scene Colours, i.e. Scenario #1\Scene #1)*

This solution includes:

1. Adding a Defined Name *(named `DATA`)* at worksheet level *(scope)* to contain all Scenarios as header with all the corresponding Scenes below each Scenario - one per cell `[A1:C4]`

[image]
Fig. 1

2. Adding a list to hold all the Scene Coulors `[E1:E5]` *- Optional if you want to have the Scene Colours as a dropdown as well*

[image]
Fig. 2

3. Adding a Dynamic Defined Name *(named `DtaVld`),* to allow the use of dropdowns to assign the Scene Colours:

Select cell `I2` and add the Dynamic Defined Name using this formula:

```
=INDEX(DATA,1+RIGHT(I$1,1),MATCH($G2,INDEX(DATA,1,0),0))
```

[image]
Fig. 3

4. Adding a range *(Table of Results)* to assign Scene Colours  `[G1:N5]`

*As the “Table of Results” basically assigns Scene Colours to Scenarios\Scenes I took the liberty to move the Scene Colour field to the beginning of the table.*

[image]
see Fig. 4

Enter the following Formulas\DataValidations in the *“Table of Results”* by Field:

**Scenarios:** To allow selection of Scenarios add a Data Validation using this formula to point to the header of the Defined Name `DATA`

```
=INDEX(DATA,1,0)
```

[image]
see Fig. 5

**Scene Colour:** To allow selection of Scene Colours add a Data Validation pointing to the list in `$E$2:$E$5`

**Selection #n’s** *(all cells `I2:N5`)*: Add a Data Validation pointing to the Dynamic Defined Name `DtaVld`